# php query to select first date in array and group into online and offline based on given condition

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP program that outputs an array of data from a selected date range.

I am working on an online and offline status report.
When there is a 30mins time gap, it should be marked as offline date range.
Here is my array example below:

```
array (size=21)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '2022-08-10 10:27:53' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '2022-08-10 10:28:03' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '2022-08-10 10:28:13' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '2022-08-10 10:28:23' (length=19)
  4 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '2022-08-10 11:28:33' (length=19)
  5 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '2022-08-10 12:28:50' (length=19)
```

From above array the time difference between each indexes is less than 2 minutes except for index [4] and [5], This makes index[4] and index[5] offline category.

Below is my php program but I do not have a properly means of achieving my goal of categorizing into online and offline

```
$imeis = "864180032315686";
        $imeis = explode(",", $imeis);
        $dtf = '2022-08-10 09:27:52';
        $dtt = '2022-08-10 09:30:52';

        $result = '<table class="report" width="100%"><tr align="center">';
            $result .= '<th>'.$la['OBJECT'].'</th>';
    
            $result .= '<th>TIME FROM</th>';
    
            $result .= '<th>TIME TO</th>';
    
            $result .= '<th>DURATION</th>';

            $result .= '<th>STATUS</th>';
            
        $result .= '</tr>'; 

        $data = array();
        $data['online'] = array();
        $data['offline'] = array();
        $total_online_count = 0;
        //iterate over imeis
        for($c = 0; $c<count($imeis); $c++)
        {
            $imei = $imeis[$c];
            $accuracy = getObjectAccuracy($imei);
            $route = getRouteRaw($imei,$accuracy,$dtf,$dtt);


            $result .= '<tr align="center">';
                
            $result .= '<td>'.getObjectName($imei).'</td>';

            $result .= '<td></td>';

            $result .= '<td></td>';

            $result .= '<td></td>';

            $result .= '<td></td>';

            $result .= '</td>';

            for($d = 0; $d<count($route); ++$d)
            {
                $route1 = $route[$d][0];
                
                if(isset($route[$d+1][0]))
                {
                    $route2 = $route[$d+1][0];
                
                }else{
                    $route2 = $route[$d][0];
                }
               

                $route1_dt = strtotime($route1);
                
                $route2_dt = strtotime($route2);
               
                $route_dt_diff = $route2_dt - $route1_dt;
                $is_data_on = false;
                $is_data_off = false;
                

                //iterate through route loop, time difference more than $gsValues['CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'] should be flagged as offline duration
                if($route_dt_diff < ($gsValues['CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'] * 60))
                {
                    //online array here
                    $is_data_on = true;
                    $dt_online_start = $route1;
                    $dt_online_end = $route2;
                    $total_online_count += $route_dt_diff;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    //offline array here
                }
            }
            
        }
```

My goal is to have a table like below

| IMEI | Time From | Time To | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 864180032315686 | 2022-08-10 10:27:53 | 2022-08-10 10:28:23 | ONLINE |
| 864180032315686 | 2022-08-10 10:28:23 | 2022-08-10 12:28:50 | OFFLINE |

I do not have idea on how to go around these despite having given the array already, but my php code seems not working and I need help and suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: Where does `10:17:53` come from?  I find your [mcve] to be Unclear.  If we don't need `alarm` please remove it from your sample data.  Please remove all irrelevant data and code.

Comment: Please always present your array data as `var_export()` format text so that volunteers can instantly use it in their preferred sandbox.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have added your corrections and removed all irrelevant data, only date information is left for better clarity

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple. Calculate the difference between **Time From** and **Time To**, and build a condition according to the result. Take this example to find out:-

```
$datetime1  = new DateTime('2020-10-11 16:52:52');
$datetime2  = new DateTime('2020-10-13 16:52:52');
$interval   = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $interval->format('%a days');

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$diffInSeconds = $interval->s; 
$diffInMinutes = $interval->i; 
$diffInHours   = $interval->h; 
$diffInDays    = $interval->d;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).